# Avoid iOS EventKit startDate and endDate overlapping with existing events

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar, eventkit

I can successfully add some events to the Calendar, using this simple code snippet:

```
 var eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: {
            granted, error in
            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                println("Access granted to calendar \(granted)")
                println("No error or error is simply \(error)")
                
                var event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                event.title = fullTitle
                event.startDate = startDate
                event.endDate = endDate
                event.notes = "This is a note"
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpanThisEvent, error: nil)
                println("Saved Event")
            }
```

I can handle errors and authorisation issues, but I want to be sure that there's no overlap, not even by a minute when I add a new Calendar event with an existing one.

By default it just "overload", I could set many events at the very same time but I don't want this behaviour... So, what I mean is that startDate and endDate should be set on an empty slot, if something is already set in between I want to be notified in advance.

I read the EventKit documentation but is kind of cumbersome to me, also the examples I found vary in galore from the code I got, which is working fine.

Comment: I guess I might not fully understand the question, but why not get all events within start and end date/time and if there is more than 0, deny adding a new one?

Comment: @Krumelur That may be an option, could you please give me a hint or quote me the code/method to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Check out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html

Comment: @Krumelur Thank you very much. I read it but it isn't clear to me, it's all Objective-C code and it might be deprecated, in a nut shell, I couldn't find a method that may check if there's any event within my dates.

Comment: What do you mean, "it's all Objective-C"? Of course it is, it's for iOS/Mac. It's either ObjC or Swift - what are you using?

Comment: Hey @Krumelur thank you again. I'm all about Swift and I'm swift using Swift, but Objective-C it's sort of weird to me now... Although I never got the syntax truly... In any case, I am abusing your time. I just needed an method/object that I can pass startDate and endDate and get some return... That 0 would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search if the event exists before you save it. If the event exists just doesn't add it.

To find if event exists you can use something like:

```
NSString *predicateString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title == '%@' AND location == '%@' AND notes == '%@'", event.title, event.location, event.notes ];
    
    NSPredicate *matches = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    
    NSArray *datedEvents = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:[eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:event.startDate endDate:event.endDate calendars:nil]]; //search in all calendars
    
    NSArray *matchingEvents = [datedEvents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matches];
```